# Android maps set multiple markers invisible

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I hide multiple markers on Android Maps V2?

I have 10 markers. 5 a certain type of cinema and 5 another type.

If I use the below code only the last marker disappears.

Marker cinema1,cinema2;

cinema1 = gMap.addMarker......

cinema1 = gMap.addMarker......

cinema2 = gMap.addMarker......

cinema2 = gMap.addMarker......

and so on

On Click Event

cinema1.setVisible(false);

This only sets the last marker = to cinema1 to invisible (obviously) so the questions is how can I set all 5 markers invisible without declaring a Marker for each?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of makes invisible all markers better to clear your map...

Comment: I want all 10 markers on the map when the app starts. If the user clicks a radio button for cinema1 I want all 5 markers for cinema2 to be invisible. If they click radio button for cinema2 then cinema2 markers reappear and cinema1 markers disappear.

Comment: @JCom09 have you found answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

You should create list with markers and manipulate with its help.

```
Marker dilers1,dilers2;
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
dilers1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.755823,37.622315)).title("Melbourne"));
dilers2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.765823,37.612315)).title("Melbourne2"));
markers.add(dilers1);
markers.add(dilers2);

public void changer(){
   for (Marker mkr: markers) {
       mkr.setVisible(false);
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an [Hashmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) if your types have an ID

```
Hashmap<Integer, Marker> markers = new Hashmap<Integer, Marker>()

markers.Add(cinema1.getID(), gMap.addMarker(...));
markers.Add(cinema2.getID(), gMap.addMarker(...));
markers.Add(cinema3.getID(), gMap.addMarker(...));
```