# Hide multiple markers on a map Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Does anyone know if it is possible to hide a group of markers by selecting a radio button?

eg: I have a map with a bunch of markers located at different cinemas. CinemaABC and CinemaDEF

If I click the radio button CinemaABC then all the markers for CinemaDEF should be hidden so only CinemaABC's markers are shown.

I dont want to cluster cinemas.

I built my app using Android Studio using Google-Maps API 2.

Thanks

Comment: This worked for me:
[hide marker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38639568/6202040)

Comment: This worked for me :
[hide marker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38639568/6202040)

Answer (score 0):

It's directly not possible but you can clear google map and add marker again at your points of interest See bellow code it may be solve your problems

```
private void drawMarker(LatLng point) {
    google.clear();
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
    markerOptions.position(point);

    // Adding InfoWindow title
    markerOptions.title("Location Address");

    // Adding InfoWindow contents
    markerOptions.snippet(markerLocationAddress);

    // Adding marker on the Google Map
    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have a clear idea of your question, But i come to understand that, You are searching for a specific place and more makers are showing all around the Map.

You cant hide the markers but you can do as per bhadresh devani suggested you and another alternative is you can make the makers invisible but setting a minimum radius on the map. so you wont see more markers on the map.